# Cassandra Windows 10 Access Violation

Tags: windows, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

**EDIT:** Although yukim's workaround does work, I found that by downgrading to JDK 8u251 vs 8u261, the sigar lib works correctly.

- Windows 10 x64 Pro
- Cassandra 3.11.7

NOTE: I have JDK 11.0.7 as my main JDK, so I override JAVA_HOME and PATH in the batch file for Cassandra.

Opened admin prompt and...

java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

python --version

```
Python 3.8.5
```

**EDIT #1** switched to Python 2.7.18 and that at least made cqlsh start and error out on no server where on 3.8.5 it wasn't even running.

echo %JAVA_HOME%

```
c:\progra~1\java\jdk1.8.0_261
```

When I run cassandra.bat, I get:

```
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
    It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
    for performance and stability reasons.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
    Performance of this node will suffer.
    Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\bin>CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset (Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataInputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubset (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;ILorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubsetSize (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)I
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/AbstractCommitLogSegmentManager.advanceAllocatingFrom (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogSegment;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/BaseIterator.tryGetMoreContents ()Z
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stop ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stopInPartition ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush (I)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeExcessSlow ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeSlow (JI)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly (I)J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/UnfilteredSerializer.serializeRowBody (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/rows/Row;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/SerializationHeader;Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.indexes (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/IFilter/FilterKey;)[J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.setIndexes (JJIJ[J)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeVInt (JI)[B
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:17,701 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/C:/Program%20Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,108 Config.java:534 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=null; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_compaction=true; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_reads=true; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=null; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@235834f2; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_materialized_views=true; enable_sasi_indexes=true; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; file_cache_round_up=null; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=null; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=0; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=0; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_flush_in_batches_legacy=true; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_negotiable_protocol_version=-2147483648; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=256; otc_backlog_expiration_interval_ms=200; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; repair_session_max_tree_depth=18; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=null; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=127.0.0.1}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; snapshot_on_duplicate_row_detection=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@5656be13; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,110 DatabaseDescriptor.java:381 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,113 DatabaseDescriptor.java:439 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 2018MB
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,114 DatabaseDescriptor.java:443 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 2018MB
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,249 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,250 DatabaseDescriptor.java:773 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,384 JMXServerUtils.java:252 - Configured JMX server at: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7199/jmxrmi
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,391 CassandraDaemon.java:490 - Hostname: W-2UA8232KLJ-0
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,391 CassandraDaemon.java:497 - JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_261
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,393 CassandraDaemon.java:498 - Heap size: 7.883GiB/7.883GiB
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,393 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 5162240(5041K) committed = 5177344(5056K) max = 251658240(245760K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,394 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Metaspace Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 19777368(19313K) committed = 20316160(19840K) max = -1(-1K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,394 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Compressed Class Space Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 2361872(2306K) committed = 2490368(2432K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,395 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 1006632960(983040K) used = 201345160(196626K) committed = 1006632960(983040K) max = 1006632960(983040K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,397 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Par Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 125829120(122880K) used = 0(0K) committed = 125829120(122880K) max = 125829120(122880K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,397 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 7331643392(7159808K) used = 0(0K) committed = 7331643392(7159808K) max = 7331643392(7159808K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,398 CassandraDaemon.java:505 - Classpath: C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\conf;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/airline-0.6.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/apache-cassandra-3.11.7.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/apache-cassandra-thrift-3.11.7.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/asm-5.0.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/caffeine-2.2.6.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/concurrent-trees-2.4.0.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/guava-18.0.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/hppc-0.5.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/jackson-annotations-2.9.10.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/jackson-core-2.9.10.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/jackson-databind-2.9.10.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/javax.inject.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/jctools-core-1.2.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/jflex-1.6.0.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/jna-4.2.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/joda-time-2.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/jstackjunit-0.0.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/lz4-1.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/metrics-core-3.1.5.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/metrics-jvm-3.1.5.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/metrics-logback-3.1.5.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/ohc-core-0.4.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/ohc-core-j8-0.4.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/reporter-config-base-3.0.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/reporter-config3-3.0.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/sigar-1.6.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/snowball-stemmer-1.3.0.581.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/stream-2.5.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\build\classes\main;C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\build\classes\thrift;C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,399 CassandraDaemon.java:507 - JVM Arguments: [-Dcassandra, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Dcassandra.logdir=C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\logs, -Dcassandra.storagedir=C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\data, -Xloggc:C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7/logs/gc.log, -ea, -XX:+UseThreadPriorities, -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xss256k, -XX:StringTableSize=1000003, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -XX:-UseBiasedLocking, -XX:+UseTLAB, -XX:+ResizeTLAB, -XX:+UseNUMA, -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000, -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled, -XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways, -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10, -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M, -Xms8192M, -Xmx8192M, -Xmn1200M, -XX:+UseCondCardMark, -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\sigar-bin, -XX:CompileCommandFile=C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\conf\hotspot_compiler, -javaagent:C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar, -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199]
WARN  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,405 StartupChecks.java:169 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 16:36:18,410 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=19812, tid=0x000000000000481c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_261-b12) (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.261-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\bin\hs_err_pid19812.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT #2** per request here is the crash dump log (posting a few interesting snippets due to post limit):

```
Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000070641c60 is an unknown value
RBX={method} {0x0000014170463c88} 'getFileSystemListNative' '()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/FileSystem;' in 'org/hyperic/sigar/Sigar'
RCX=0x000001414f753688 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000028ab53e5b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001414f753490
RSP=0x00000028ab53e3e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001414f753490
RBP=0x00000028ab53e598 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001414f753490
RSI={method} {0x000001416ccc0488} '<init>' '()V' in 'java/lang/Object'
RDI=0x0000000000118e98 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000032 is an unknown value
R9 =
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005]


Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getFileSystemListNative()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/FileSystem;+0
j  org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getFileSystemList()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/FileSystem;+1
j  org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getFileSystemMap()Lorg/hyperic/sigar/FileSystemMap;+19
j  org.apache.cassandra.utils.SigarLibrary.<init>()V+79
j  org.apache.cassandra.utils.SigarLibrary.<clinit>()V+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks$7.execute()V+0
j  org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks.verify()V+30
j  org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup()V+41
j  org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate()V+46
j  org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 2.609 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000001415132849c method=java.lang.CharacterDataLatin1.digit(II)I @ 82
Event: 2.610 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000001415132a514 method=java.lang.CharacterDataLatin1.digit(II)I @ 82
Event: 2.616 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000014151438564 method=java.util.Arrays.equals([B[B)Z @ 2
Event: 2.621 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000001415135d188 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 19
Event: 2.621 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000001415135d188 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 19
Event: 2.624 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000001415135d188 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 19
Event: 2.624 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000001415135d188 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 19
Event: 2.631 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Uncommon trap: reason=predicate action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000001415143734c method=java.lang.String.regionMatches(ZILjava/lang/String;II)Z @ 63
Event: 2.667 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000001415142b318 method=java.util.regex.Matcher.search(I)Z @ 86
Event: 2.747 Thread 0x000001416d7d6230 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000141514cdaa0 method=java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 113
Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 2.455 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/cassandra/config/EncryptionOptions$ClientEncryptionOptionsCustomizer> (0x00000005c6938828) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u261\295\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfi
Event: 2.455 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/cassandra/config/TransparentDataEncryptionOptionsBeanInfo> (0x00000005c694d288) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u261\295\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDi
Event: 2.456 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/cassandra/config/TransparentDataEncryptionOptionsCustomizer> (0x00000005c695e860) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u261\295\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\system
Event: 2.464 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x00000005c69ef788) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u261\295\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 710]
Event: 2.464 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x00000005c69f0358) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u261\295\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 710]
Event: 2.466 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x00000005c6a02b98) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u261\295\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 710]
Event: 2.466 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x00000005c6a030c8) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u261\295\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 710]
Event: 2.468 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x00000005c6a03ea0) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u261\295\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 710]
Event: 2.468 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x00000005c6a043d0) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u261\295\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 710]
Event: 2.717 Thread 0x000001414f753490 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': javax/management/remote/rmi/RMIServerImpl_Skel> (0x00000005c83b4838) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u261\295\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210

Events (10 events):
Event: 2.788 loading class org/apache/cassandra/net/MessagingService done
Event: 2.789 loading class org/hyperic/sigar/FileSystemMap
Event: 2.789 loading class org/hyperic/sigar/FileSystemMap done
Event: 2.789 loading class org/apache/cassandra/net/MessagingServiceMBean
Event: 2.789 loading class org/apache/cassandra/net/MessagingServiceMBean done
Event: 2.790 loading class org/hyperic/sigar/FileSystem
Event: 2.790 loading class org/hyperic/sigar/FileSystem done
Event: 2.790 loading class org/apache/cassandra/net/MessagingService$2
Event: 2.790 loading class org/apache/cassandra/net/MessagingService$2 done
Event: 2.791 loading class org/apache/cassandra/net/MessagingService$1
```

Comment: What does *C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\bin\hs_err_pid19812.log* tell you?

Comment: @KenWhite I posted some of the crash log... can't post all of it due to size limit. Getting some class not found exceptions...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think it is sigar-lib that cassandra uses that is causing the problem (especially on the recent JDK8).

It is not necessary to run cassandra, so you can comment out this line from cassandra-env.ps1 in conf directory:
https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.7/conf/cassandra-env.ps1#L357

Comment: Hi, this did fix the crash... just curious what the side effects of this is? If it is not needed, why is it included? :) Don't want to run into some issue down the road.

Comment: Sigar is used for checking running environment so that users can have proper (recommended) configuration on OS. If you are running for development, then removing is fine.

Comment: Saw a blog where the guy used u251 and he didn't have the sigar issue, so I switched out u261 for u251 and it works without commenting out sigar.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it.

Comment: resolved it in a hard way. Despite commenting out line #357, I was getting the JVM crash due to 'sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4'. This is with Cassandra 3.11.7 and Oracle 64bit Java 1.8.0_261. Instead of finding which other file (I suspect so) still asking to load sigar files from '..\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\sigar-bin', I just renamed the sigar-folder to something like this '\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\[TEMP] sigar-bin'. This stopped those files from loading, and the Cassandra server is up.

Comment: @KGhatak Thanks! It worked. But, wouldn't that create any problems in the future, though I don't know how to utilize that sigar-bin?

Comment: @manikanta nvsr - The very fact that we need to go for such a hack indicates that, and I presume, Cassandra is least interested to support non-enterprise users like us who are trying to set it up in a Windows laptop. This also means that for any purposes other than playing with it to get started or so, we should go for enterprise grade installation set up such as cloud native or physical cluster of RHEL nodes or the likes.

Comment: I was with JAVA SE Dev Kit 8 u271 and so I downgrade to u251. It works for me.

Answer (score 21):

#### Fixing the Casandra server error

- idea to solve this error is to stop that file from loading.
- I got similar error like this "Initializing SIGAR library"

[image: error recognition and error report file]

- so error in SIGAR library
- Now go to error report file

```
E:\installed_software\apache-cassandra-3.11.10\bin
```

- And open log file using notepad

[image: error report file]

- Now go to problematic frame file and

```
E:\installed_software\apache-cassandra-3.11.10\lib\sigar-bin
```

- change the name of that file from "sigar-amd64-winnt.dll" to "sigar-amd64-winntt.dll".
- This will stop that file from loading.

Comment: tried both answers, this one worked for me

Comment: Faced exactly same issue. It got resolved after rename file from "sigar-amd64-winnt.dll" to "sigar-amd64-winntt.dll"

Answer (score 1):

renaming sigar-amd64-winnt.dll" to "sigar-amd64-winntt.dll" solved the issue. Also i have to add JAVA_HOME to cassandra.bat file in my windows laptop explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I installed JDK 8u351, Cassandra 3.11.14, and python 2.7.
Then I configured the environment variables according to [this link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-cassandra-on-windows)
Then I wanted to run cassandra but I couldn't run and I faced to this fatal error:

## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

## EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=6308, tid=0x0000000000000418

At last, I changed the name of the file from "sigar-amd64-winnt.dll" to "sigar-amd64-winntt.dll" (this file exists in the lib folder in your installed Cassandra application).

Answer (score 0):

Installing this Windows patch https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999 as per the update in the post https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/30#issuecomment-742627481 helped in my case.