# why I can not install Cassandra 3.11.10 even though I used JDK 1.8.0?

Tags: java-8, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

```
WARN  [main] 2021-03-11 13:06:54,319 StartupChecks.java:169 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  [main] 2021-03-11 13:06:54,332 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=2384, tid=0x0000000000004c34

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_281-b09) (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.281-b09 mixed-mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.10\bin\hs_err_pid2384.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Comment: - I got the same error I posted my solution there [See the similar error related to " Problematic frame: C [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4] " ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66568615/13087749)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cassandra Windows 10 Access Violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144295/cassandra-windows-10-access-violation)

Answer (score 0):

This is problem regarding sigar library . Go to library section in your cassandra installed directory. Go inside lib/sigar-bin folder rename sigar-amd64-winnt.dll this file to something else. I guess this has some issues. I dont know why it is used. but for now it is working in  mine. Thanks for posting.