# Cassandra: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have donwloaded cassandra 3.11.10, and when I try to run command 'cassandra -f' in /bin folder, I get error as:

```
INFO  [main] 2021-06-26 11:15:52,511 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=21192, tid=0x0000000000005264
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_291-b10) (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.291-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Could you check whether this works? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144295/cassandra-windows-10-access-violation

Comment: Try to install in Linux if it was possible. In windows there is many problems.